# WordPress Plugins, jquery noconflict issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am newbie to jQuery and javascript !!

To avoid any conflict in WordPress Plugin, I've included the following line in my JS file that is outside my page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var yourFunc = function() {
//code
};
yourFunc();
});
```

Now when I click on plugin settings (which uses this javascript), opens the link in new tab and in that, an "more option" (toggle function) is not working. That might be due to WordPress or other, I dont know.

So Experts, Please help me, I want to open the links in same tab. I tried a lot but all in vain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the $ in your JS? If so, while using jQuery in noConflict mode, you need to pass the $ in as a parameter to use as an alias for jQuery objects.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```